# Error when creating new instance of model but is fine when using Model::Find()

Tags: mysql, model, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm sure that the set primary key in the model is working since I used the model's `Find()` function which relies on the set primary key and it gives the correct data.

The problem rises when creating a new one like this code:

```
$new = new Book();
$new->title = 'pogi';
$new->save();
```

It generates this error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY' (SQL: insert into `books` (`title`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?)) (Bindings: array ( 0 => 'pogi', 1 => '2013-10-09 02:18:53', 2 => '2013-10-09 02:18:53', ))
```

Model:

```
class Book extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'books';
    public $primaryKey = 'book_id';
}
```

P.S:
I don't know if this will help but I ran this sql code which changes things:

```
ALTER TABLE books
CHANGE link ibooks_url varchar(255),
ADD COLUMN kindle_url varchar(255),
ADD COLUMN kobo_url varchar(255),
ADD COLUMN ibooks_id varchar(255),
CHANGE book_id kindle_id varchar(255),
ADD COLUMN kobo_id varchar(255),
ADD COLUMN ibooks_id varchar(255),
CHANGE id book_id varchar(255);
```

Comment: Is that id your primary key? "CHANGE id book_id varchar(255);"

Comment: Yes sir it is, it's also auto increment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE books MODIFY book_id INT NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE books DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE books MODIFY book_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

The problem is that the auto_increment is still set to the "id" field.

Run the above sql code to change the auto increment to the latest primary key "book_id", when changing the name of the primary key with auto increment, you need to reset the primary key so that you can set the auto increment to the new name that you assigned.

Comment: I tested this, and it works! Thank you so much! I'll accept later